# OS X 10.7 with XQuartz can't X11Forward to remote Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding

The problem:

X11 forwarding doesn't seem to work properly.

The setup:

I'm using `ssh` to connect from my Mac to an Ubuntu box, trying to open `xterm`. The Mac is  OS X 10.7 running XQuartz 2.7.2 (xorg-server 1.12.2) Ubuntu is 10.04.

On the Mac, `$DISPLAY` says `/tmp/launch-FG8ND0/org.macosforge.xquartz:0`, and this is the debug log from ssh. The Mac is named powerbook, and the Ubuntu box is named lucid. The Ubuntu box has X11Forwarding enabled, and I've tried both the ssh options `-X` and `-Y`… Nothing seems to work.

```
Last login: Fri Jul 27 14:12:40 on ttys001
petriborg at powerbook in ~
$ echo $DISPLAY
/tmp/launch-FG8ND0/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
petriborg at powerbook in ~
$ ssh -vv -Y lucid
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/petriborg/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to lucid [10.10.10.115] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/petriborg/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/petriborg/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/petriborg/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/petriborg/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 118/256
debug2: bits set: 531/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'lucid' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/petriborg/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug2: bits set: 508/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/petriborg/.ssh/powerbook_rsa (0x10ae25030)
debug2: key: /Users/petriborg/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/petriborg/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/petriborg/.ssh/powerbook_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp e9:6d:e6:87:c2:6f:86:74:a4:0a:23:41:e4:c4:08:75
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to lucid ([10.10.10.115]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/X11R6/bin/xauth  list /tmp/launch-FG8ND0/org.macosforge.xquartz:0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 0
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Linux lucid.local 2.6.32-41-generic-pae #89-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 27 23:59:24 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Welcome to Ubuntu!
 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

*** System restart required ***
Last login: Fri Jul 27 14:12:52 2012 from powerbook
petriborg@lucid: ~ $ 

petriborg@lucid: ~ $ echo $DISPLAY

petriborg@lucid: ~ $ xterm
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: 
xterm:  DISPLAY is not set
petriborg@lucid: ~ $ grep X11 /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
petriborg@lucid: ~ $
```

Comment: what is ForwardX11Trusted set to on lucid?  If you -X does your DISPLAY get set on lucid?

Comment: Nope, -X and -Y behave the same

Comment: have you disabled IPV6 on lucid?  can you run sshd in debug mode (/usr/bin/sshd -ddd ) on lucid to see what it is doing?

Comment: I have disabled IP6 on the lucid box yeah, could that be the problem? I'll try the -ddd

Comment: yes that is the problem.  IF IPV6 is disabled it won't build the connection,  Issue with sshd..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've indicated IPV6 is disabled on lucid, that is probably the problem, due to an openssh  issue

try to add  `AddressFamily inet` to  /etc/ssh/sshd_config  and it should resolve the issue